# How do I fetch two rows of data from a single table but show the result as a single row of data?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the table called vehicle_data
[image: vehicle table]

and I want to calculate the two-row **same** **date** data in a single row data like

```
SELECT * FROM vehicle_data WHERE `date` = '2019-12-27'
```

[image]

```
session_start();
require('../db_config.php');
$date= date('Y-m-d');
$date = $_GET['date'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicle_data WHERE `date` = '$date' AND `camera_id`=1,2";
$result = $conn->query($sql); 

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$myObj->bicycle = $row["bicycle"];
$myObj->motorcycle = $row["motorcycle"];
$myObj->wheeler_3_4 = $row["wheeler_3_4"];
$myObj->seden_car = $row["seden_car"];
$myObj->pick_up = $row["pick_up"];
$myObj->mini_bus = $row["mini_bus"];
$myObj->boro_bus = $row["boro_bus"];
$myObj->covered_van = $row["covered_van"];
$myObj->all_truck = $row["all_truck"];
$myObj->trailor_truck = $row["trailor_truck"];
$myObj->total_vehicle = $row["total_vehicle"];

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;
}
```

Comment: please add code that you tried

Comment: Kindly do not post images , also share your efforts/code then only we can help you.

Comment: What is your expected result

Comment: Are you trying to avoid duplicate records? Can you please post your code?

Comment: @VipindasKS sir now posted, please see

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth, sorry about that sir, thank you for suggesting me

Comment: `AND camera_id=1,2` <- is it valid syntax?

Comment: @degr yes I have camera id like this which is also in the table column

Answer (score 1):

Just use SELECT SUM

```php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=myscript;host=localhost','root','', $opt);

$sql = "select date, SUM(bicycle) AS bicycle,  SUM(motorbicycle) AS motorbicycle, ...
from vehicle_data
where `date` = :date AND `camera_id` in (1,2)"

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['date' => $date]);
$data = $stmt->fetch();
```

And don't just put variable in raw sql, use bindParam to prevent SQL injection. And PDO is better.

Comment: sorry sir am not getting this code 

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('date', $date);

Comment: @SatyajitBarik myqli doesn't have named parameters, you have to use `?` placeholders. Read the documentation or switch to PDO so you can do it like the answer.

Comment: `camera_id = 1,2` should be `camera_id IN (1, 2)`

Comment: @Barmar yes, thx for reminding.